# Pulling paginated json data from API using Python

Tags: python, json, api, pagination

**The problem:**
I have an online CRM system with limited reporting functionality. There is a restful API available and I am able to pull the data I need from within PowerBI. The issue is that API paginates the data in either 100s or 200s. At the current state there are over 45k records I need to pull every time I need to refresh the data. In PowerBI it takes over 30 mins. I was thinking (maybe incorrectly) that Python script may be a solution. As I am no Python expert I aided myself with google search and came up with the below simple script to pull all the records.

```
import json
import requests

base_url = "https:##############"
entity = "payment"
session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update({'Authorization' : 'Bearer TOKEN',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Beacon-Application': 'developer_api'})


def main_request(base_url, entity):
    r = session.get(base_url + entity)
    return r.json()

def get_pages(response):
    pages = round(response['total'] / 100)
    return pages  


data = main_request(base_url, entity)
results = main_request(base_url, entity)['results']

pages = get_pages(data)

#print(pages)
#print(results[0])



payments = []

for page_num in range(pages + 1):
     full_url =base_url + entity + '?page=' + f"{page_num+1}"
     data_ = session.get(full_url).json()

     payments.extend(data_['results'])



print(len(payments))

with open('payments.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(payments, f)
```

The problem is that it still takes relatively long time but also creates a large json file ~300Mb for 45k records.
Can someone point me in the right direction? What are the best practices?

Comment: `The problem is that it still takes relatively long time but also creates a large json file` - 1. It will take long because you still need to send a lot of requests. For 45k records with 100 entries per page it's 450 requests. 2. Similarly with data. The more entries, the more size they'll take. It's on average <7kB per entry.

Comment: Thank you. So I suppose this is just how it is? I am assuming there would be a way to pull only changed and new records from the API as there is a modified/created timestamp or maybe have some reference table form the first pull and only pull changed / updated but it's beyond my skills I'm afraid :)